# Oracle SQL retrieving data across 3 tables

Tags: sql

Here are the relations:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  name    varchar2(15) not null, 
  ssn      char(9),
  primary key (ssn),
  foreign key (superssn) references employee(ssn),
);

CREATE TABLE project (
  pname      varchar2(15) not null,
  pnumber    number(4),
  primary key (pnumber),
  unique (pname),
);

CREATE TABLE works_on (
  essn   char(9),
  pno    number(4),
  primary key (essn,pno),
  foreign key (essn) references employee(ssn),
  foreign key (pno) references project(pnumber)
);
```

Q: Retrieve the names of all employees who work on every project.

I guess I am being asked to query for all the employees that participate in a project, sorting by Project name. Any idea how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic `divide` problem.

Try this.

```
   SELECT name FROM Employee 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pnumber FROM project WHERE pnumber   
      NOT IN (SELECT pno from Works_on WHERE employee.ssn = works_on.essn))
```

Or for all the projects and their employees,

```
  SELECT employees.name, project.pname FROM employees 
    INNER JOIN works_on ON employees.ssn = works_on.essn
      INNER JOIN project ON works_on.pno = project.pnumber;
```

Comment: Hey Scotch, this returned something, but just 1 name.

Comment: So is there only one person that's involved in all projects? that's what it's supposed to return as your description said. You wanted the employees names that work on every project. Did you want the EmployeeName and ProjectName for all projects?

Comment: Yes, I think it's asking to provide a list of all the projects and their respective employees.

Comment: @maxspiderx I added a query for that.

Comment: This worked, thanks!

However, is there any difference between your query with the joins and mine?

SELECT pname, name
FROM employee, project, works_On
where employee.ssn = works_on.essn and works_on.pno = project.pnumber

Comment: As far as I know, doing a `join` the right way (in the from clause) would be better performance wise than doing it in the where clause. However, most query optimizers (Oracle included) would likely optimize it to the same query. You could try both of them and use `EXPLAIN` to see the differences, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.NAME FROM
EMPLOYEE E,
PROJECT P,
WORKS_ON WO
WHERE 
E.SSN = WO.ESSN
AND WO.PNO = P.PNUMBER
ORDER BY P.PNAME;
```

Check if that works to you.

You can try this too:

```
SELECT E.NAME FROM
(SELECT E.NAME, P.PNAME FROM
    EMPLOYEE E,
    PROJECT P,
    WORKS_ON WO
    WHERE 
    E.SSN = WO.ESSN
    AND WO.PNO = P.PNUMBER
    ORDER BY P.PNAME);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this tonight.

However, suppose I want to sort this by pnumber instead of pname, but don't want the pnumber column to show up in my query, how would I do this? I originally had the same answer as you except I had:

    order by p.pnumber

and that yielded an error.

Comment: Hi Jeyvison, your first solution returned 109 results with tons of repetitions. Your second response returned this: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: Put a `DISTINCT` at the first solution.